# tikz dead end arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, edge

In tikz, I am looking for a "dead end" arrow (not literally an arrow), like this:

[image]

Is there a arrow specification option similar to [->,>=latex] that draws such a line? I usually use this kind of drawing style:

```
\node[draw,rectangle] (x) at (0,0) {node};
\node (y) at (0,-1) {};
\draw (x) edge[<options>] (y);
```

If not, how would you solve it? I want both the vertical and horizontal line be anchored to some invisible node, so that I can move the node afertwards for repositioning purposes without fiddling with the lines manually. If I move the invisible node to either side, the dead-end-edge shall behave like normal edges and result in a straight but angular edge connecting both nodes. The orthogonality of the end shall be kept.

Unfortunately I don't know how this kind of edge is called, so I don't know what to search for in the existing questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an old arrow tip for just this, `|`. E.g. `\draw [-|] (0,0) -- (1,1);`

For all things arrow tips, see section 16.5 *Reference: Arrow Tips* in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). It describes the `arrows.meta` library. This library introduces a slightly different way of defining arrow tips, `-{Bar[]}`, where the brackets can contain options for customizing the arrow tip.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle] (x) at (0,0) {node};
\node (y) at (0,-1) {};
\draw [-|] (x) edge (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```